# "Disallow: /test/programmming" or "Disallow: /programming"?

Tags: robots.txt

I manage a site under WordPress. We had to change the site URL to `example.com/test`. So, I now have 2 properties in Search Console: one with the root domain (`example.com`). The other with the subdirectory (`example.com/test`).

Whenever I search `site:example.com` in Google, it returns all the indexable URLs which is `example.com/test` for the home page. The domain root `example.com` is therefore not indexable anymore.

In robots.txt, I like to disallow some URLs such as `example.com/test/programming`.

Should I disallow: `/programming` OR disallow: `/test/programmming` so that `example.com/test/programming` becomes blocked?

Comment: Do you expect a different page to get indexed if you block this URL? Or do you want the document `example.com/test/programming` not get crawled at all, no matter under which URL?

Comment: i want this url to not crawled at all  (example.com/test/programming ) just so you know my site url is example.com/test not the root domain

Answer (score 0):

`Disallow` values always represent the beginning of the URL path.

For `https://example.com/test/programming`, the path is `/test/programming`.

So, `Disallow: /test/programming` would block URLs like these:

- `https://example.com/test/programming`
- `https://example.com/test/programming/`
- `https://example.com/test/programming.html`
- `https://example.com/test/programming/foo/bar`

And `Disallow: /programming` would block URLs like these:

- `https://example.com/programming`
- `https://example.com/programming/`
- `https://example.com/programming.html`
- `https://example.com/programming/foo/bar`

Comment: /the problem is my site is a wordpress i use example.com/test as my home page my sitemap is example.com/test/siteamp.xml and my robots file is under example.com/robots.txt i just want to know which url the bots read before the /

Comment: @emma: I don’t understand why you think it’s a problem. The sitemap URL is irrelevant in this context, and your robots.txt is at the correct place. The bot crawls the URLs it can find linked somewhere. If you use/link the URLs with `/test/`, this is what the bot will visit.